# PHP ftp_put get exact error

Tags: php

I have a basic ftp upload script. 
The script was working fine and then suddenly one day it stopped. 
All I am getting it the error message 'There was a problem while uploading..'

I am wondering if there is a different code I can use so I can narrow it down to get a more specific error message so I can debug better what is causing the problem?

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.****.biz";
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "Nittan****S1", "nits*****!");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id,  $nameoffile,  $nameoffile, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $nameoffile\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $nameoffile\n";
} 

 // close the connection
 ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I took the exact same code and I put it on a different server and the code worked fine. So there must be something on the server itself that it causing the problem. But how can I narrow the problem down?

Comment: Is it emitting any warnings?  (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Comment: I believe your code is correct, If you are still having problems after choosing ftp_pasv() you should refresh the connection through ftp_close() / ftp_connect() after x files and/or y GB have been transfered. or may be  How about using error_get_last() ?

Comment: Nothing in error reporting, and nothing error_get_last. I already have a ftp-close, but it doesn't help the problem